# How do I preserve Tagetes Filifolia?

Tags: food-preservation, herbs

It's turning to fall, and have a lot of Tagetes Filifolia to preserve. How should I preserve it?

Comment: Have you tried any of the common methods for preserving herbs?

Comment: and drying, freezing. For wild mushrooms I've heard of pickling with alcohol.

Comment: @acoder Did some of your comment get cut off, or is it just drying and freezing you've tried?

Comment: i'm asking for the best practice for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find anything on it but this paper on [The Archaic Diet in Mesoamerica](https://www.academia.edu/12154526/The_Archaic_Diet_in_Mesoamerica_Incentive_for_Milpa_Development_and_Species_Domestication) (page 334, Table 1) suggests that drying is a traditional method used to preserve Tagetes Filifolia flower and leaves.